# find files matching either some string or some other string in bash

Tags: bash, find

I wonder how to specify to the command find for searching files with names matching some string or some other string.

For example, if I want to look for files that match either *dat or *txt under current directory, how to specify?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Belongs on superuser.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
find . \( -name \*.dat -o -name \*.txt \)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find /path -type f \( -iname "*.txt" -o -iname "*.dat" \)
```

Comment: You're missing a quote after *.txt